# Should we encode the email and password form client side (Angular app) before we sent it to server?

Tags: codeigniter-3, angular2-forms

When submit an form login, should i encode (such as sha1) the email and password to make it is confidential ? or we just make it on the server ?

Comment: definitely yes, you should, this would prevent anyone the user details who is sniffing the packets maybe it be from his unsecured network or otherwise

Comment: Ok, someone told me that HTTPS protocols do it, you don't need to encode, is it right ?

Comment: yes, if you are using `https` then its safer . there is very nice explanation here https://security.stackexchange.com/q/133453/139623